# sudden 505 error getting to my website on linux apache php

Tags: linux, laravel, apache, laravel-5

**suddenly i am getting this error**

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@kibakibi.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

**and in apache error logs**

```
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:15.226845 2018] [core:error] [pid 19115] [client 5.255.250.144:60384] End of script output before headers: index.php
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:17.217114 2018] [:error] [pid 19098] [client 5.188.10.11:51242] EasyApache PHP config file not found: /php.conf.yaml
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:17.217148 2018] [core:error] [pid 19098] [client 5.188.10.11:51242] End of script output before headers: index.php
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:17.221895 2018] [:error] [pid 19098] [client 5.188.10.11:51242] EasyApache PHP config file not found: /php.conf.yaml
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:17.221921 2018] [core:error] [pid 19098] [client 5.188.10.11:51242] End of script output before headers: index.php
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:20.958247 2018] [:error] [pid 19113] [client 54.36.148.28:59462] EasyApache PHP config file not found: /php.conf.yaml
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:20.958275 2018] [core:error] [pid 19113] [client 54.36.148.28:59462] End of script output before headers: index.php
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:20.963483 2018] [:error] [pid 19113] [client 54.36.148.28:59462] EasyApache PHP config file not found: /php.conf.yaml
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:20.963510 2018] [core:error] [pid 19113] [client 54.36.148.28:59462] End of script output before headers: index.php
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:21.772834 2018] [:error] [pid 19089] [client 66.249.66.21:41503] EasyApache PHP config file not found: /php.conf.yaml
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:21.772862 2018] [core:error] [pid 19089] [client 66.249.66.21:41503] End of script output before headers: index.php
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:21.777434 2018] [:error] [pid 19089] [client 66.249.66.21:41503] EasyApache PHP config file not found: /php.conf.yaml
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:21.777458 2018] [core:error] [pid 19089] [client 66.249.66.21:41503] End of script output before headers: index.php
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:21.911961 2018] [:error] [pid 19093] [client 84.201.133.27:54553] EasyApache PHP config file not found: /php.conf.yaml
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:21.911994 2018] [core:error] [pid 19093] [client 84.201.133.27:54553] End of script output before headers: index.php
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:21.917152 2018] [:error] [pid 19093] [client 84.201.133.27:54553] EasyApache PHP config file not found: /php.conf.yaml
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:21.917178 2018] [core:error] [pid 19093] [client 84.201.133.27:54553] End of script output before headers: index.php
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:21.974311 2018] [:error] [pid 19090] [client 5.188.10.11:53661] EasyApache PHP config file not found: /php.conf.yaml
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:21.974334 2018] [core:error] [pid 19090] [client 5.188.10.11:53661] End of script output before headers: index.php
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:21.979110 2018] [:error] [pid 19090] [client 5.188.10.11:53661] EasyApache PHP config file not found: /php.conf.yaml
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:21.979133 2018] [core:error] [pid 19090] [client 5.188.10.11:53661] End of script output before headers: index.php
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:22.944860 2018] [:error] [pid 19115] [client 54.36.149.63:42200] EasyApache PHP config file not found: /php.conf.yaml
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:22.944888 2018] [core:error] [pid 19115] [client 54.36.149.63:42200] End of script output before headers: index.php
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:22.949539 2018] [:error] [pid 19115] [client 54.36.149.63:42200] EasyApache PHP config file not found: /php.conf.yaml
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:22.949562 2018] [core:error] [pid 19115] [client 54.36.149.63:42200] End of script output before headers: index.php
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:23.190276 2018] [:error] [pid 19091] [client 100.43.81.113:55308] EasyApache PHP config file not found: /php.conf.yaml
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:23.190302 2018] [core:error] [pid 19091] [client 100.43.81.113:55308] End of script output before headers: index.php
[Fri Jan 19 12:42:23.194975 2018] [:error] [pid 19091] [client 100.43
```

Comment: restart apache service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rebuild the easy apache php settings and everything started working again.

(if you are on local just restart the apache if it does not work reinstall the apache and php services).